# how to get all pins from pinterest ? getting only 50 pins

Tags: php, api, pinterest

I get only top 50 pins at a time using this code

```
https://api.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/users/lorihiney/pins/
```

is there any way to get all pins of a particular user .

Comment: Have you got any solution for this? I have been trying using official Pinterest API, but there is no way to fetch other user's pins from that. But https://api.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/users/lorihiney/pins/ doesn't return the time stamps of the pins.

Comment: yes i did it check my below answer second link will return date

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Amitesh. But That is for boards related pins right? I have only user name to fetch the pins. So I can't do that using that link right?

Comment: actually pins which present on profile is actually they are boards pins.so that why you need board information to get pins.otherwise it will not happen.

Comment: https://api.pinterest.com/v1/boards/lorihiney/diet/pins/?access_token=xxxxx&limit=100&fields=id,link,counts,note,url,image My doubt in this URL is about lorihiney/diet. what are these two parameters? from where can get these? Because I have only one param with me that is user name which is like opiproducts.

Comment: lorihiney is user and diet is board  name

Comment: Ohh it's working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced this problem too when trying to use the API and it left me pulling my hair out!!

I ended up creating a recursive function using info I found online to get all the child pages of a board, while also pushing the pins to an array.

I first saved all my boards to a MYSQL table, then the pins in another. Saves on API calls and made finding duplicates much easier (that was what I was trying to use it for)!

```
$pins=array();

function findchildren(&$array, $i){
 global $pins;

 if (true == $i){return;}

    foreach($array as $k=>$v){
     array_push($pins, $v['data']);
       if(!empty($v['page']['next'])){
       $newar = curlfunction($v['page']['next']);
       findchildren($newar, false);
       }
    }
 }
```

So something like:

```
$board = curlfunction('https://api.pinterest.com/v1/boards/lorihiney/diet/pins/?access_token=xxxxx&limit=100&fields=id,link,counts,note,url,image');
findchildren($board, false);
```

You'd just need to create the cURL function to get the data!!

My Pinterest account has 31 boards and 1890 pins. Works a treat for me after spending AGES trying to figure it out. Hope that it helps somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it using the undocumented widget API. If you use the [Official Pinterest API](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/) you can have a user log in, and fetch all of their Pins/boards/etc using simple [pagination](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview/#pagination). Easiest way to get started is to check out the [API Explorer](https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/api-explorer/). The endpoint you're interested in is `v1/me/pins/`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: i want pins of others user just like board.Is it possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Now i am getting all information :

This link will give pin info

```
https://api.pinterest.com/v1/boards/lorihiney/diet/pins/?access_token=xxxxx&limit=100&fields=id,link,counts,note,url,image
```

we also get link of next page. 1st hit will give 100 pins the after that it will give link of next page. like this:

```
https://api.pinterest.com/v1/boards/officialpandora/put-a-ring-on-it/pins/?access_token=XXXXX&fields=id%2Clink%2Ccounts%2Cnote%2Cimage%2Ccreated_at%2Curl&limit=100&cursor=!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

This link will give the information of board:

```
https://api.pinterest.com/v1/boards/stars-stars-stars?access_token=XXXXXXX&fields=id,counts
```

All you need is access token which will you get 
[access token](https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/access_token/)

for further details:
[pinterest Official Doc](https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/api-explorer/)